# jQuery not working after inline CSS moved

Tags: jquery, html, css

I initally had all of my CSS inline, at which time the inline jQuery was working perfectly without issue, it's only current purpose being to fade in the whole body of the page. When I moved the CSS and JavaScript to an external file, my jQuery quit working. I tried adjusting the code of the jQuery, my javascript detector function, and my stylesheet, and was unable to get it working again even when I switched back to inline. I tried using developer tools as well, but quite frankly I don't think I'm adept enough to use them properly.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzkgekut/

```
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace('no-js','js');</script>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>content</body>
<script src="fadeIn.js"></script>
</html>

//fadeIn.js contents, before the code broke I didn't use anything except line 2 with no issue.
document.ready(function(){
$('body').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: Try using `$(function(){...});` instead of `document.ready`.

Comment: can you please reproduce the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net/#run

Comment: using function instead of document.ready didn't work.   @Lal I was unable to get it to work on jsfiddle either.  I feel like the body isn't properly setting to invisible to allow fadeIn to function, but I don't know why moving my CSS to not inline would affect that.  it's direct copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify `body` in your selector, and you should create a `div` with an `id` and make sure you select that `id` in your JQuery. 
Make sure you specify the `display: none;` property for your `id`'s CSS, as your div will need to appear through fading in.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me, as it worked before I moved everything from inline to external. This solution worked, thank you for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it. Would you mind explaining to me why the div specification was necessary?

Comment: The div specification isn't absolutely "necessary". But it's good practice, as you can systematically structure and organize the parts of your webpage that you want to fade in. You can use "body" as a selector, but it's really way better practice instead to create a div with an id. You can select elements, ids, and classes as well. I may have been unclear when I said that you "cannot" specify body. You "can", but it's better to use the div specification. Thanks!